# FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates gives Incompatible Types Error

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, location-services, android-fusedlocation

I am using Google Play services to get current location. When I am using `requestLocationUpdates` method it gives red lines saying; 
    **Incompatible types. Required: android.location.Location. Found:com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult**

```
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

`this` refers to LocationListener. I already implement **com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener** and override `onLocationChanged` method but still red line exists. To be able to sure I tried this version also;

```
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                }
            });
```

This also gives **same** error. Method parameters are GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, LocationListener.
I don't understand where is the mistake. Any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post you your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assign mLastLocation.
`LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);`
Since your class implements LocationListener, you're supposed to receive your location changes on `onLocationChanged(Location location)`.
Did you see the formal samples and explanation ? if not, this will be usefull : http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Read more on : http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)

Comment: Yes that makes sense. But onLocationChanged does not called. So I used this also, `mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);` Without using this line, latitude and longitude returns 0. By using it, latitude and longitude are the last location's values and I am waiting new results in onLocationChanged method. What is needed to called onLocationChanged method? How much should I change my location?

Comment: I saw the mistake yes it is shame. I cant assign the `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this)` command to Location object. Thanks!